# axios.post is displaying user inputs in search bar

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm trying to build a React app with Hooks, with a node.js express server and postgreSQL database.
The first step is user registration but I'm experiencing some weirdness with axios (and also a proxy error which may or may not be related?)

**Desired behaviour:** User completes all fields and clicks submit, data is sent to backend, stored in a database and a user id assigned, response returned to front end and all fields clear.

If the user submits incomplete information, it is not stored and the response from the backend triggers an error message to the user.

**Situation 1**: The user completes all fields.
**Outcome 1**: Behaviour is as expected EXCEPT
(a) the user data also appears in the search bar, including the password in plain text, and persists after the data is saved e.g
http://localhost:3000/?first=Lucy&last=Who&email=who%40example.com&password=something#/
(b) The following error:

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /register from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.
> See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).

[note: I am using create-react-app, 3000 is the port used by the dev server, I'm using 5000 for my server]

**Situation 2:**  The user enters incomplete information and clicks submit.
**Outcome 2:** The data appears in the search bar as above and is sent to the backend, the input fields clear but apparently no response is returned and the error message is not triggered.

**Situation 2.1:** user sends the *same* incomplete information again
**Outcome 2.1:** the error message is triggered.

**Situation 2.2:** user sends *different* incomplete information
**Outcome 2.2:** the error message clears.

---

**Code**  (apologies if this is too much/not enough, not being sure where the problem lies makes it a bit tricky to work out what someone else might need to know)

register.js

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "./axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Register() {
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [first, setFirst] = useState("");
    const [last, setLast] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

const formDeets = {
    first: first,
    last: last,
    email: email,
    password: password,
};

function submitReg() {
    console.log("formDeets", formDeets);

    axios
        .post("/register", formDeets)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log("response.data: ", response.data);
            clearAll();

            if (response.data.success) {
                console.log("success");
            } else {
                setError("true");
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("register.js error in post register", err);
        });
}

function clearAll() {
    console.log("clear all called");
    setFirst("");
    setLast("");
    setPassword("");
    setEmail("");
}

return (
    <section className="register container">
        <div className="register-component">
            {error && (
                <div className="error">
                    Registration failed. Please complete all fields and try
                    again.
                </div>
            )}
            <form>
                <label htmlFor="first">first name</label>
                <input
                    onChange={(event) => setFirst(event.target.value)}
                    type="text"
                    name="first"
                    placeholder="first name..."
                    value={first}
                />
                <label htmlFor="first">last name</label>
                <input
                    onChange={(event) => setLast(event.target.value)}
                    type="text"
                    name="last"
                    placeholder="last name..."
                    value={last}
                />
                <label htmlFor="email">email address</label>
                <input
                    onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
                    name="email"
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="email address..."
                    value={email}
                />
                <label htmlFor="password">choose a password</label>
                <input
                    onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="choose a password..."
                    value={password}
                />
                submit
                <input
                    type="submit"
                    value="click to accept cookies and register"
                    onClick={() => submitReg()}
                />
            </form>


        </div>
    </section>
);}
```

server.js (just the relevant part, I think)

```
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    console.log("/register route hit");
    console.log("req body", req.body);

const first_name = req.body.first;
const last_name = req.body.last;
const email = req.body.email;
const password = req.body.password;
let user_id;

if (!first_name || !last_name || !email || !password) {
    res.json({
        success: false,
    });
    return;
}

hash(password).then((hashpass) => {
    db.addUser(first_name, last_name, email, hashpass)
        .then((results) => {
            console.log("results", results.rows[0]);
            user_id = results.rows[0].id;
            req.session.userId = user_id;
            res.json({ success: true });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("err in addUser: ", err);
            res.json({ success: false });
        });
    return;
});
}); //end of register route



server.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}`));
```

and finally, I'm calling axios from axios.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

var instance = axios.create({
xsrfCookieName: "mytoken",
xsrfHeaderName: "csrf-token"
});

export default instance;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers have default behaviour for when you submit a form.

It is causing the browser to navigate to a new URL after running your JS.

You need to prevent the default behaviour of that submit event.

---

> ```
> onClick={() => submitReg()}
> ```

There doesn't seem to be any reason to use an arrow function here. `submitReg` doesn't use `this` so binding `this` with an arrow function is pointless.

```
onClick={submitReg}
```

---

Now your function will be passed an event object. Use it to stop the default behaviour of a form submission.

```
function submitReg(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log("formDeets", formDeets);
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been fighting with this for days and you fixed it in 5 minutes! The binding came from the fact that I'm converting this from an old app written with classes, and for some reason I haven't been able to find the new syntax for prevent default since 'event' is now deprecated and vs code won't accept it, so this answer has solved two issues for me.